# How do I search for javascript in the firefox debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox

Very simply, what is the equivalent in firefox to chromes "search" tab within the browser console? Specifically firefox developer edition.

[image: chrome search]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Debugger -> Search scripts (Ctrl-P). There are multiple options in that dialog to search the current file, or all files. It searches HTML and CSS as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I also found that depending on the prefix I put in the search will determine what it will search, for example, putting a "!" before what I search will tell firefox to search all files.